How do i delete these loose edges?
This is my first time trying blender, so I'm not too familiar with all settings yet, but I have been trying everything that I found online to fix this problem. I have a few loose edges on my model that are connected to the body, but when I go into edit mode they can't be selected. When I try the cleanup on loose things, it doesn't do anything.. When i select the entire body and invert my selection, it doesn't select the loose edges. What can I do to fix this???


Try dissolving them, btw you have a quite messy mesh here.

@Lukasz-40sth, how do i dissolve them?

hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

ive added a link to the post @moonboots

You have overlapping vertices, the Solidify modifier generates these edges that you show, to fix that select all in Edit mode and merge by distance (M)
